# Configuring Spring Kafka to use DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.3 and am trying to configure Spring `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` with a `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` to send error records to a different topic. The new DLT queue is created and a record is inserted but the message body is empty. I was expecting the message body to be populated with the original JSON body for future analysis.

Here is the configuration I have so far. Any idea where I'm going wrong? Not sure if its to do with using `kafkaTemplate<Object, Object>` where as the message producer uses `kafkaTemplate<String, Message>`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka

public class ListenerConfig {

    @Value("${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;  

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> kafkaTemplate;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.class);
        props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, JsonDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, JsonDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.KEY_DEFAULT_TYPE, "java.lang.String");
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.VALUE_DEFAULT_TYPE, "com.test.kafka.Message");
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "com.test.kafka");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "json");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Message> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
        consumerConfigs());   
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Message> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Message> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());  
        factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(kafkaTemplate), 3));
        return factory;
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "test")
    public void receive(@Payload Message data,
                    @Headers MessageHeaders headers) {
        LOG.info("received data='{}'", data);

        System.out.println(data.getMessage());

        headers.keySet().forEach(key -> {
           LOG.info("{}: {}", key, headers.get(key));
        });
    }
```

Comment: Swordfish, did you manage to get the original payload in the .DLT? I am getting them as null, even after Gary's enhancement [in the link he provided](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/987)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` simply publishes the incoming `ConsumerRecord` contents.

When the `ErrorHandlingDeserializer2` detects a deserialization exception, there is no `value()` field in the `ConsumerRecord` (because it couldn't be deserialized).

Instead, the failure is put into one of two headers: `ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_EXCEPTION_HEADER` or `ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.KEY_DESERIALIZER_EXCEPTION_HEADER`.

You can obtain the details with

```
Header header = record.headers().lastHeader(headerName);
DeserializationException ex = (DeserializationException) new ObjectInputStream(
    new ByteArrayInputStream(header.value())).readObject();
```

with the original payload in `ex.getData()`.

We should probably enhance the recoverer to do this when it detects such a header is present and the `value()` is `null`.

[I opened a new feature issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/987).

Comment: Great thanks for the explanation Gary. So for now, to achieve the functionality I want, do I disable the SeekToCurrentErrorHandler / DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer and put that code in a custom error handler?

Comment: You can either replace the recoverer (subclass the `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` and override `createProducerRecord()`), or simply put that code in whatever consumes from the dead letter topic if it receives a `null` `value()`.

Comment: Thanks for the support guys.

Comment: @GaryRussell, i saw that the enhancement #987, is done(as per the link you gave). Thanks. But after using the DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer, i am still getting null in .DLT. Does this mean that the Recoverer will not "publish" the original payload and that i need to do something in order for it to do so ?

Comment: In another comment elsewhere, you indicated you are using 2.2.9. If you look at the right hand side of that issue, you will see it was added in 2.3 M1 - milestone 1 of the 2.3 release. The enhancement is in the current release 2.3.1; this release requires Spring Boot 2.2 (scheduled to be released today); Boot 2.2.0.RC1 (release candidate) is available now.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gary, did not "notice" the `2.3 M1`. Release `2.3.1`, in Boot `2.2.0.RELEASE` works!